how can i search in datagridview after adding rows from excel in c#
i have this code for importing rows from excel
public void ReadExcelFile(string filePath)
{
    // Create an Excel application
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

    // Suspend the DataGridView's layout logic
    dataGridView.SuspendLayout();

    // Read data from the worksheet and populate the DataGridView
    for (int row = 1; row <= excelWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(
            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value,
            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value);
            //excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value,
            //excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value);
    }

    // Resume the DataGridView's layout logic
    dataGridView.ResumeLayout(false);

    // Close Excel objects
    excelWorkbook.Close(false);
    excelApp.Quit();
}

and for to search
private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Filter rows based on the first column ("No")
    string searchValue = textBoxSearch.Text.Trim();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _team1List.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
        {
            row.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

but i am getting error as "Unsaved new line cannot be made invisible."
how can i make search newly added rows to datagridview when user start typing?
